# Styling wheel pickers in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have searched around for a solution how to style WheelPickerStyle-pickers in SwiftUI, especially if you want to have multiple pickers side by side. Finally I got rid of the gap between the pickers by using padding and clipping on the individual pickers. I'm not sure if this is a good solution to use some arbitrary padding (might break in the future, or maybe if the user is using a bigger font).

Now to my second problem, and the main question of this post. Can I change the color/opacity of the selected items? I'm using a background color in my project other than black/white, and the "selection bar" is almost not visible.

Edit: I found out that I can use the .contrast-modifier on each Picker, but even with a high value it's not enough for my taste.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var hours = 0
    @State private var minutes = 0
    @State private var seconds = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {

            Picker("Hours", selection: $hours) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 24) { hour in
                    Text("\(hour)")
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            .padding(.trailing, -15)
            .clipped()

            Picker("Minutes", selection: $minutes) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 60) { minute in
                    Text("\(minute)")
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            .padding(.horizontal, -15)
            .clipped()

            Picker("Seconds", selection: $seconds) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 60) { second in
                    Text("\(second)")
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            .padding(.leading, -15)
            .clipped()

        }
        .padding()
        .background(.blue.gradient)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

With a background color other than white/black:
[image: With a background color other than white/black]

With a white/neutral background you can see the bar much better:
[image: With white background]

This is how I'd like to style it:
[image: This is how I'd like to style it]

Comment: I didn't try on latest iOS 17, but before that it was not possible to customize wheel pickers completely. Basically you had 2 options: either settle on just "light" or "dark" mode variety provided by iOS itself as the only variety there ever will be. Or, develop your own wheel picker (not that hard really)

Answer (score 2):

You can using the SwiftUI-Introspect library:

```swift
Picker("", selection: $selector) {
    // your items
}
.pickerStyle(.wheel)
.introspect(.picker(style: .wheel), on: .iOS(.v13, .v14, .v15, .v16, .v17)) { picker in
    picker.subviews[1].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // or any color you want
}
```

you can find the library here: [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/swiftui-introspect)